# Filter repeating two digits pattern in SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I would like to filter some string numbers that have repeated two digits more than 3 times. For example, if it contains "121212", it will not be filtered, but if it contains "12121212" it will be filtered. I am trying to find a way to solve it using regular expression but could not find it.

Comment: Oracle <> SQL Server. What RDBMS are you *really* using? If SQL Server it has no (built-in) support for Regex.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, use a regular expression to match two digits and then use a back-reference to check that the digits repeat 3-or-more times. Then to exclude those rows add `NOT` to the filter:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(value, '(\d\d)\1{3,}')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '121212' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '12121212'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123121212'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| 121212 |
| 123121212 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fjz-Jpte)

Comment: your solution is correct but instead of finding the occurrence 3 times you need to check it at least if its repeating 4 times , thats what mentioned in the requirement question:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(value, '(\d\d)\1{4,}')

Comment: @fahad No, the OP wants "more than 3 times" and `(\d\d)` matches the first occurrence and then `\1{3,}` matches the next three (or more) occurrences which gives four (or more) in total. If you use `(\d\d)\1{4,}` then you are matching five-or-more occurrences which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: but your result contains value "121212" which is wrong clearly mentioned in the above question with the exact example of whats not needed

Comment: @fahad The OP wants to filter values that contain more than 3 repeats; it is ambiguous whether the question asks about filtering them in or filtering them out and this answer shows how to add the `NOT` operator to filter them out. If you want to keep them in and filter the non-matching rows out then just remove the `NOT` operator. You do not need to change the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, I tried it in Impala, but it doesn't work. Any idea why?